# Laravel eloquent find and save duplicate entry for key error when there are no duplicate values

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am updating a record in my table using laravel eloquent, in my table a field called 'sign' is unique.
My code is:

```
$oSetting = PersonalSetting::find($id);
                $oSetting->Login = utf8_decode($login);
                $oSetting->Sign = utf8_decode($sign);
                $oSetting->save();
```

The query is "update `PersonalSetting` set `login` = 'xyz', `sign` = 'abc' where id` = 4691"

When I am updating this record I am getting "Duplicate entry 'abc' for key 'sign'". But there is no other entry with sign value as 'abc'
Then how can it be a duplicate entry?